# shm_size of Docker container needs to be equal or bigger than Postgresql shared_buffers size

Tags: postgresql, docker, shared-memory

Default value of PostgreSQL shared_buffers value is 128 MB.

Default value of Docker shm_size is 64 MB.

If I run PostgreSQL in Docker and try to run VACUUM, I get error like: "ERROR: could not resize shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1221162100" to 67128544 bytes: No space left on device."

After setting shm_size to 128m VACUUM started working.

My question is, did I do the right thing and need to modify the Docker container as mentioned above, or are the two items more or less independent and it started working by accident?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL allocates `shared_buffers` and some other shared memory areas when the server starts. So I don't think that is a coincidence.